# Error when querying list/roleassignment in 2013 REST API - Need to know if a user can query a list/library

Tags: 2013, javascript, permissions, rest, roles

In sharepoint 2013, I need to check if a the current user, has access to a specific list, for that I'm using the following REST endpoint (using AJAX)

> host/_api/web/list(guid"xxxxxxxxxxx")/RoleAssignments

But i'm not able to check on the roles assigned for that list with a user that it's not an admin? The query it returns a login forma asking for a user with enough privileges

How can i check if the current user can query the items for example the "invoices" list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [List.EffectiveBasePermissions property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.effectivebasepermissions.aspx) to retrieve the
  effective permissions on the list that are assigned to the current
  user
- Use [BasePermissions.Has method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.basepermissions.has.aspx) by specifying
  [PermissionKind.ViewListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.permissionkind.aspx) to determine whether *current user could
  access List*

The example shows how to determine whether current user could access list or not:

```
function getListPermissions(weburl,listTitle) 
{
    var endpointUrl = weburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/effectivebasepermissions";
    return $.ajax({
        'url': endpointUrl,
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        }
    });
}






var listTitle = 'Pages';
getListPermissions(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,listTitle)
.done(function(data)
{
    var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);
    if (!permissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems)){
       console.log(String.format('Current user cant access {0} list',listTitle));    
    }
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Seems i have a proble with "SP.BasePermissions();"
Cant find it at pageload time, dows it depends on a specific JS file that i need to add?

Comment: SP.BasePermissions is declared in sp.js, so there is a dependency to SharePoint library, could you reference that library in your app?

Comment: Ill guess ill delay the checking of the permissions till SP.js is loaded, this could do the trick :)
$.getScript(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15/sp.js",$scope.getFilters())

Comment: Point is...when i do all that, the moment I try to excecute

permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);

"permissions" doesnt have the "initPropertiesFromJson" property :